# Clean up DOM after a Firefox add-on SDK extension Disable/Remove action is fired

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on a add-on SDK extension which uses a `pageMod` object with a content script that adds a `DIV` tag to the DOM (this tag behaves like a button) when the action button is being clicked.

I am trying to find a solution where I can delete that newly added `DOM` element when the extension is being disabled or removed and I've had no luck so far.

The first thing that I've tried was to use the `AddonManager.addAddonListener(listener)` approach where I would listen for a `onUninstalling` or a `onDisabling` event and then communicate with the content script but I got nowhere.

What I've tried next was to make use of the `exports.onUnload` solution where I tried to send a message from the `pageMod`'s worker to the content script and deal with the removal of the `DIV` from there but it seems that the content script is no longer responsive by the time the `onUnload` function is being triggered.

Is there really no way to clean up the modified `DOM` when the extension is being disabled/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your content script listen for the `detach` event.

```js
self.on("detach", function(reason){
  //remove that div
});
```

Comment: It works most of the time so thank you but sometimes it seems it is not firing since the div is not removed from any of the pages. I am quite dumbfounded by this behavior.

Comment: Also, is it just me or the FF Add-on SDK documentation is really twisted? I had previously visited this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/content_worker - which would had given me the solution - on a separate occasion but it simply wouldn't have crossed my mind that the detach event would work for a content script attached through a pageMod worker.

Answer (score 0):

In @paa's answer the "port" part is missing:

e.g., from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)

```
var oldInnerHTML = window.document.body.innerHTML;

window.document.body.innerHTML = "eaten!";

self.port.on("detach", function() {
  window.document.body.innerHTML = oldInnerHTML;
});
```

I am not using PageMod nd this works for me.